# Nakama service gets terminated on aws t2xlrage Ireland

Tags: go, github, amazon-ec2, open-source, nakama

our project run fine after half an hour gets terminated. currently our project alive and we have a problem with the nakama service getting terminated we have checked Nakama catches this error :
[Nakama service error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zR4Mx.png)

and regarding the infrastructure wise we have hosted on the AWS t2xlarge instance

we have realized that a fatal error occur in the go build in Nakama it seem mutex happed 2 goroutines try to reach the same resource at the same time and race condition happened.

We have checked server log nakam fatal error concurrent map write after that Nakama catch this exception:

```
github.com/heroiclabs/nakama/v3/server.NewRuntimeEventQueue.func1()
nakama: github.com/heroiclabs/nakama/v3/server/runtime_event.go:46 +0x92
nakama: created by github.com/heroiclabs/nakama/v3/server.NewRuntimeEventQueue
nakama: github.com/heroiclabs/nakama/v3/server/runtime_event.go:44 +0x117
nakama: goroutine 382027 [IO wait]:
nakama: internal/poll.runtime_pollWait(0x7f0df2b1c9f0, 0x72)
nakama: runtime/netpoll.go:302 +0x89
nakama: internal/poll.(*pollDesc).wait(0xc000df6580?, 0xc00019c000?, 0x0)
nakama: internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:83 +0x32
nakama: internal/poll.(*pollDesc).waitRead(...)
nakama: internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:88
nakama: internal/poll.(*FD).Read(0xc000df6580, {0xc00019c000, 0x1000, 0x1000})
```

```
nakama: goroutine 84 [select, 1 minutes]:
nakama: github.com/blugelabs/bluge/index.analysisWorker(0xc0004c04e0, 0xc0004c0540)
nakama: github.com/blugelabs/bluge@v0.1.9/index/writer.go:549 +0x7f
nakama: github.com/blugelabs/bluge/index.OpenWriter.func1()
nakama: github.com/blugelabs/bluge@v0.1.9/index/writer.go:69 +0x2f
nakama: created by github.com/blugelabs/bluge/index.defaultConfig.func2
nakama: github.com/blugelabs/bluge@v0.1.9/index/config.go:205 +0x19
nakama: goroutine 85 [select, 1 minutes]:
nakama: github.com/blugelabs/bluge/index.analysisWorker(0xc0004c04e0, 0xc0004c0540)
nakama: github.com/blugelabs/bluge@v0.1.9/index/writer.go:549 +0x7f
nakama: github.com/blugelabs/bluge/index.OpenWriter.func1()
nakama: github.com/blugelabs/bluge@v0.1.9/index/writer.go:69 +0x2f
nakama: created by github.com/blugelabs/bluge/index.defaultConfig.func2
nakama: github.com/blugelabs/bluge@v0.1.9/index/config.go:205 +0x19
nakama: goroutine 86 [select]:
```

[Nakama Fatal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0JTH.png)

Comment: So what have you considered to stop 2 instances demanding a resource at the same time?

Comment: i have re-provision the instance and I realize same problem